# exclude time periods in iCalendar

Tags: icalendar, rfc5545

i have a very simple vevent "every Monday 9 to 5" and some time periods where this event doesn't take place. like 7.8.2011 to 24.10.2011. What is the best way to represent this in iCalendar?

a lot of EXDATEs? special EXRULEs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh dear,

Exrule is deprecated now in RFC 5545, so best skip that one (although that would be neatest and most ics s/w probably still copes with it (like mine :), for compatibility )

EXDATES are valid, but gosh that would be cumbersome if you mean the whole period from 7 August to  24 October, you'd have to enter every week day

You possibly have to just create two events -  although one could 'relate' them.

I have not tried it yet, have been thinking about if for a different reason, but there is  the concept of 'RELATED-TO' with modifer RELTYPE (PARENT, SIBLING etc)

RELATED-TO;RELTYPE=SIBLING:19960401-080045-4000F192713@
        example.com

Property Name:  RELATED-TO

Purpose:  This property is used to represent a relationship or
      reference between one calendar component and another.

Value Type:  TEXT

Property Parameters:  IANA, non-standard, and relationship type
      property parameters can be specified on this property.

Conformance:  This property can be specified in the "VEVENT",
      "VTODO", and "VJOURNAL" calendar components.

Description:  The property value consists of the persistent, globally
      unique identifier of another calendar component.  This value would
      be represented in a calendar component by the "UID" property.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i think i stick with the exdates, it's easier to implement, and as my events are weekly there won't be too many of them :) Do you know if there is some limitation?

Comment: Hi  no i've never seen a limitation.  I cannot think of any reason why there should be any limit